# Flex RichText vs. Label Control

Tags: apache-flex, label, flex4, richtext, flex-spark

I have a flex project where I uses the spark RichText control quite extensively, there are places where it is possible for me to replace RichText with the Label control - (The rich text occurred due an import from Flash Catalyst).

My question is, is there any space/performance advantage in using Label over RichText, since Label seems like a much lighter option, I am building a web app, size matters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need one of these features for your text :

- Multiple formats
- Multiple paragraphs
- Text object model
- Markup language
- Inline graphics

Go with a simple Label, it's indeed lighter than the RichText. I don't know how much size and memory you will save at the end but it won't hurt doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `Label` has better performance and memory usage than `RichText`. And `Label` is the best option for simple labels.

What about application size it depends on your project's settings. If you're using RSLs (which is default option for Flex 4 projects in Flash Builder) it doesn't matter what component do you using.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe...

RichText uses the Text Layout Framework (TLF) library, which in turn builds on the Flash Text Engine (FTE) in Flash Player 10. In combination, they provide rich text layout using high-quality international typography.

The Spark architecture provides three text "primitives" -- Label, RichText, and RichEditableText. Label is the fastest and most lightweight because it uses only FTE, not TLF, but it is limited in its capabilities: no rich text, no scrolling, no selection, and no editing. RichText adds the ability to display rich text with complex layout, but is still completely non-interactive.